# How to make a Entity move towards a x and y?

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to make my Entity(A bullet) move towards a x and y,which is where the player was when the bullet was fired. so In my entity class i have -

```
   float xSpeed = 1.0F;
   float ySpeed = 0.0F;
```

if I wanted to move the entity in a diaganal line I would make xSpeed and ySpeed = 1.0F
How would I make it move in the dir of another x and y?

Thanks for the help
EDIT --
Solved,thanks for the help
To anyone else who finds this question needing help,here is my code-

```
    float xSpeed = 0;
    float ySpeed = 0;
```

then I have some maths to make it so they move at the same speed

```
   ySpeed =  ySpeed * (float) (2.5 / Math.sqrt(xSpeed * xSpeed + ySpeed * ySpeed));
   xSpeed = xSpeed * (float) (2.5 / Math.sqrt(xSpeed * xSpeed + ySpeed * ySpeed));
```

and this code to set the xSpeed and ySpeed,based on a x and y you want to move towards

```
    xSpeed = (Game.PlayerX - x) / 3;
    ySpeed = (Game.Playery - y) / 3;
```

and then,finaly,add xSpeed and ySpeed to the x and y of your entity

```
    this.x += xSpeed;
    this.y += ySpeed;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way is to set the relative x and y speeds to cover the required x and y distances in the allotted travel time:

```
float xSpeed = (targetLocation.x - currentLocation.x) / travelTime;
float ySpeed = (targetLocation.y - currentLocation.y) / travelTime;
```

If you want to travel at a predetermined speed, rather than in a predetermined travel time, do the above computations with `travelTime` set to some arbitrary value (`1.0f` would work fine, so you could simply eliminate the division). Then compute this factor:

```
float factor = desiredSpeed / Math.sqrt(xSpeed * xSpeed + ySpeed * ySpeed);
```

(Note that you'll be dividing by zero if `xSpeed` and `ySpeed` are both `0`, but that simply indicates that the current and target locations are identical. If that's a possible condition, you should include an appropriate check.) Finally, readjust `xSpeed` and `ySpeed` by the factor:

```
xSpeed *= factor;
ySpeed *= factor;
```

Note that by setting `travelTime` to `1`, this is just a sneaky way of multiplying the predetermined speed by the sine and cosine of the angle that the travel direction makes with the x axis without mentioning trigonometry at all. :)

Comment: works perfectly,thanks for the help :D,Can the desired speed be a float,as 2 is to slow and 3 is to fast :D. First post on this site,but will defo be using again,such a nice community

Comment: @JackPatrick - I was assuming everything was float. Welcome to the community, by the way.

Comment: Ok,thanks for the help,I added the solution to the first post to help others.

Comment: @JackPatrick - If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. (See [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for info about accepting answers.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the speed of the object, and the direction. Then you can use simple trig to determine the x/y displacement per step.

If you use your current algorithm your object will change speeds depending on its direction, which is probably not what you want to do.

Linear direction:
speed x = 1 
speed y = 0

Total speed = 1

Diagnol direction:
speed x = 1
speed y = 1

Total speed = 2

See the problem?  *Your speed should be constant regardless of direction.*

Use what's called a `Vector` to describe your object's direction and speed.

class Vector {
   int x; int y; float angle; float magnitude;
}

The x,y, angle and magnitude describe a triangle. The movement you want will be a point on the line of the hypotenuse of the triangle, modified by the time step your engine is using.

edit -

Imagine a Circle that has a radius of 1 unit, with it's origin at 0, 0.

Draw a line from the origin to the left side.  You get a line 1 unit long, that intersects the circle at (1,0)

Now, draw a line from the origin at a 45 degree angle to the edge of a circle.

You'll also get a line 1 unit long, however the X/Y coordinate where the line intersects the circle will be (0.7,0.7) NOT (1,1).

I do not have an ide in front of me, so please someone edit if my math is wrong here, but I beilive you'll want something like this:

newPositionX = currentX + ( cos ( angle ) * speed * timeStep )

newPositionY = currentY + ( sin ( angle ) * speed * timeStep )

Comment: Actually, in the second case, total speed is sqrt(2), not 2.

Comment: @TedHopp It should be sqrt(2), that's the problem. The way that Jack describes his code the speed is 2.  Ie the object moves left/right, and then up/down in the same time frame that it would only move left/right in the other direction.

Comment: @TedHopp Or I might need more coffee. You are correct of course, a triangle with two sides of 1 length has an opposite side of sqrt(2)

Comment: More coffee -- I'm with you there!

Comment: @TedHopp Does that formula look right? I haven't done this sort of stuff in awhile.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're defining `angle`, but if it's the traditional way with the +x axis being zero and positive angle moving toward the +y axis, then you need to reverse `sin` and `cos` in your formulas.

Comment: @TedHopp I thought something like that.